# Borland C++ linker error c file include

Tags: c++, linker, include, borland-c++

I'm trying to build a C++ program with borland C++ Builder V5.5. Everything works fine until
I tryed to call a function defined in a c file. The compiler works finde but linking is not working. The linker is not able to find the function called from c++ file. The .obj file is gernerated and part of the project xml file. Do anybody now how I can solve this error.
To be sure that there are no side effects, I start a new project just calling c function call in constructor. The Project structure looks the following:

Form1.h defines Constructor and includes header where the c function is defined

Form1.cpp implements Constructor and call the c function

test.h defines an void function "void abc();"

test.c includes test.h and implements an void function "void abc() {}"

Unresolved external "abc()" referenced from ...unit1.obj

Do anyone have an idea??

Here some code

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Multicopter_Model.h"
#include "Unit1.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
abcdefg();
return;
}
```

_

```
#ifndef RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_
#define RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_

void abcdefg();

#endif */
```

_

```
#include "Multicopter_Model.h"
/* Model initialize function */
void abcdefg()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See C++ FAQ Item [[32.4] How can I modify my own C header files so it's easier to #include them in C++ code](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.4). (Read the whole of [section 32](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) actually.). Use:

```
#ifndef RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_
#define RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif 

void abcdefg();

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif 
#endif */
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Borland C++ specifically, but if you're declaring something in C++ code that was built as C you typically need to put `extern "C" { ... }` around the declaration. So, in this case, your `Multicopter_Model.h` file would want to say something like this:

```
#ifndef RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_
#define RTW_HEADER_Multicopter_Model_h_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void abcdefg();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

The reason for this is that in order to support features such as overloading, an object file built from C++ code has something called *name mangling* applied to it, whereby (e.g.) a function `foo` that takes an `int` and returns an `int` might actually be called something like `foo__Rint_Aint` to encode that information. (Note 1: Real name mangling conventions are more concise and cryptic. Note 2: In theory the same could be achieved by means other than name mangling, but in practice everyone does name mangling. Note 3: Different compilers do different forms of name mangling.) So when the C++ compiler sees the declaration of `abcdefg` without the magic annotation to tell it "this is really C, not C++", the name gets mangled and the compiled code actually expects to find a function called (in my made-up name-mangling convention) `abcdefg_Rvoid_Anone` or something. That function doesn't exist because the C compiler that built `Form1.obj` doesn't do C++ name-mangling, so the linker can't find what it's looking for.

There's a bit of a clue hidden in the linker's error message. You'll notice that it says it couldn't find `abcdefg()` rather than just `abcdefg`. That's because the argument list is encoded into the name it's looking for. The linker is kindly reporting a human-readable version of the name rather than whatever mangled monstrosity it was actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For function overloading and overriding to work in C++, all C++ compilers adds information to the function name (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B). C doesn't, so when you have a prototype in C++ the generated symbol name will not be the same as the one generated by a C compiler.

See the other answers on how to fix this.